# Make sure a method to a function has been await'ed for in Jest

Tags: async-await, jestjs

I have a function like this (the code is simplified to make this code more readable)

```
import Adapter from "adapter-package";

const adapter = new Adapter();

async powerOn(): Promise<MyClass> {
  const myClass = new MyClass();
  await adapter.powerOn();
  return myClass;
}
```

as you can see I am using `await` on the call of `adapter.powerOn()`. Now I am writing unit tests for this using Jest.

```
it("can power on the adapter", async () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(Adapter.prototype, "powerOn");
  const myClass = await MyClass.powerOn();
  expect(myClass).toBeInstanceOf(MyClass);
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenAwaitedFor();
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  spy.mockRestore();
}, 10000);
```

The test that I have underlined does not exist, but it is what I would like to test. Can I know if a method I have called has been waited for?

*edit:*

Will Jenkins pointed out that it is not clear what I am asking. Basically I want to make sure that the Promise returned by `adapter.powerOn()` has been resolved by the time my function has been resolved. Because I already had an issue where I accidentially had removed the `await` before `adapter.powerOn()`.

async powerOn(): Promise {
  const myClass = new MyClass();
  adapter.powerOn();
  return myClass;
}

So when I called my function with

```
await powerOn();
```

that function was resolved, but it did not await the call to `adapter.powerOn()` and I had to spend some time debugging. So I would like to make sure that `adapter.powerOn()` is resolved by the time `await powerOn()` completes.

Comment: it's not entirely clear why your trying to test - can you explain in a bit more detail?

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing it out, I added an explanation. Does that make the thing more clearly?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
it("can power on the adapter", async () => {
  let hasResolved = false;
  const spy = jest.spyOn(Adapter.prototype, "powerOn");

  const myClass = await MyClass.powerOn();
  expect(myClass).toBeInstanceOf(MyClass);

  let hasResolved = false;
  //if it has been awaited then this should complete
  spy.returnValues[0].then(()=>{
      hasResolved=true;
  })
  expect(hasResolved).to.be.true;
  spy.mockRestore();
}, 10000)
```

Comment: I believe something similar to this would work (I upvoted) but I found a simpler solution

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setInmediate` to wait for all pending promises:

```
const flushPromises = () => new Promise(setImmediate);

it("can power on the adapter", async () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(Adapter.prototype, "powerOn");
  await expect(MyClass.powerOn()).resolves.toBeInstanceOf(MyClass);
  await expect(flushPromises()).resolves.toBeTruthy();
}, 10000);
```

This test first checks if `powerOn` resolves and returns an instance of `MyClass` and then checks if every pending promise has been resolved or rejected.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found:

```
import { inspect } from "util";

it("waits for the adapter to have been powered on", async () => {
  const spy = jest
    .spyOn(Adapter.prototype, "powerOn")
    .mockImplementation(() => new Promise<void>(res => setTimeout(res, 0)));
  await Sblendid.powerOn();
  const spyPromise = spy.mock.results[0].value;
  expect(inspect(spyPromise)).toBe("Promise { undefined }");
}, 10000);
```

the line

```
spy.mock.results[0].value
```

will get me the promise returned by my mock. Using `util.inspect` on a promise

```
expect(inspect(spyPromise)).toBe("Promise { undefined }");
```

will give me `"Promise { undefined }"` on a fulfilled promise (that is returning `undefined`) and would return `"Promise { <pending> }"` if it weren't fulfilled, that is how I test it has been resolved (fulfilled) when `await Sblendid.powerOn();` completed.